# NHibernate.Linq And CompareTo String

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I'm using Linq and Hibernate and trying to compare to Strings one from a variable and the other from a Class Linked to Hibernate, the code:

```
   bindingSource.DataSource = (from search in Repository.GetAll()
                               where search.cod_coluna.CompareTo(CurrentRecord.cod_coluna) > 0
                               orderby search.cod_coluna select search).Take(1);
```

And i get an Exception in Runtime, QueryException: Cannot use subqueries on a criteria without a projection.

What i do now?

Comment: cross-posted (just in case anyone answers there first): https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=999214

Comment: What is the code for your Repository.GetAll() function?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that CompareTo isn't something that can be mapped to SQL.

What type is cod_coluna? You may be able to use == or != if you don't really need CompareTo.